# Can flint be obtained from gravel that a player placed when it is mined?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to get some flint in a Minecraft server and had some gravel. According to what I read, I could get flint from gravel that I placed myself.

I started trying and it was unsuccessful. I then tried for a few more times but all did not work.

I'm on Minecraft 1.12.2 Forge client and Waterfall 1.12.2 server with plugins. I don't know if this is intentional or is a feature with Waterfall or some plugins of the server. If you could get flint from mining gravel you placed, it would make no sense (at least to me)! Or is this only a feature for newer versions(eg 1.16)?

What is going on here?

Edit: I also tried this in Singleplayer on the same version and it also did not work. Are the stuff that I read lying to me or am I just very unlucky?

Edit 2: I'm not using a Silk Touch tool

Comment: Vanilla Minecraft makes no distinction whatsoever between naturally spawned and placed gravel, and never did. What 3rd party servers do is a different matter.

Comment: OTOH the gravel must be broken by player - dropping it onto a torch etc won't produce flint.

Comment: Are you getting flint from naturally generated gravel? It could be that one of your plugins is disabling flint entirely, either due to a bug or because it's changing the crafting system and having you get flint or flint-based items some other way. It may also help if you list your plugins.

Comment: Do you have any mods running?  You say you're on a Forge client.  Some mods cancel the drop chance of flint and instead make a crafting recipe - usually 3 gravel, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Tal I do have mods running, but they all are utility mods which boost FPS and improve PVP.

Comment: illumina (speedrunner) will often place gravel and break it while walking to try to get flint while moving to save time

Comment: By the way ... If you have a lot of gravel you need to mine for flint, you can place a torch with a solid block (e.g. dirt or cobblestone) above it. Place all you gravel on the solid block and then remove the solid block. The gravel will fall down on your torch and be mined into blocks you can pick up.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can get flint from it even if you placed it. Flint has a small random chance of dropping. If you mine the block with fortune enchantment, it will be more likely to drop flint. If you use a tool with maximum fortune level of III (3), it will have a 100% chance of dropping flint--i.e., it will always drop flint. If you use a tool with silk touch enchantment, it will NEVER drop flint. You may have been using silk if you are having 0 luck with it.

Comment: The chance for gravel to drop flint is specifically 10% per dig, according to the Minecraft Wiki.

Comment: Note that the gravel needs to be mined by a player to drop flint, just dropping it on a torch does not yield flint

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get flint from gravel you placed yourself.

Given a 10% chance to drop flint, you have a 0.515% chance to not get any flint after mining 50 gravel - `[(1-0.1)^50]*100`. You might have just gotten really unlucky. Or, a mod on your server might have affected your ability to get some (though you say this was replicated in smp, so probably not that)